# Sticky footbar wrong placement on device orientation change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a sticky footbar that's fixed to the bottom using `position: absolute` and `bottom:0`

When I load the page on Android Chrome in landscape mode and scroll to the bottom of the page, the bar is sticky at the bottom. If I try to switch to the portrait mode at that point, the bar sticks to the same place as it was in the landscape mode, so it ends up being in middle of screen not at the bottom.

When scrolling to top after that, it sticks back to the bottom. So I figured out that the address bar is what's causing the problem as it's hidden on orientation change so its height ends as extra space at the bottom of the page and the sticky bar above that extra space.

I tried scrolling to top of page to forcefully show the address bar but nothing happens as there is actually no scroll bar. It's just the fact that the address bar being hidden.

Comment: I think you need to change it to `position:fixed`, no?

Comment: @NewToJS I don't think the OP needs position:flxed as they mention "scroll to the bottom of the page, the bar is sticky at the bottom." If the footer had to be fixed at just the bottom of the viewport, then position:fixed would have been appropriate, not at the bottom of the page.

Comment: The bar is fixed to the bottom of the page not to the viewport so position absolute on footer along with position relative on html is required

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Check the solution, the relative position should be on body not html.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code snippet:

```css
body {
  height: 1400px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div> Footer </div>
```

Now consider this snippet:

```css
body {
  height: 1400px;
  position:relative;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div> Footer </div>
```

That's the **likely problem** you have with your code. Unless you set relative position to your `body` tag, the absolute positioning won't work as intended. You need to set the `position:relative` on the **footer's parent container** (which most likely is the **body tag**)

Comment: Tried this but its not working well when height is not an exact value like your example

Comment: @MichaelSamuel That height on body was just to demonstrate when the footer is down below. You can just set the min-height to 100%.

Comment: Setting to 100% doesn't work as well. Only works on `html` tag not `body`

Comment: @MichaelSamuel Well, then not much can be said without you providing the markup and CSS.